# Get all groups that have access permissions to a folder using Python

Tags: python, directory

On Windows, when you right click on a folder and select 'Properties' and then the 'Security' tab and then click 'Advanced' this shows an Advanced Security settings for the folder, including a 'Permission entries' section, which details group access.

I'm trying to find a way in Python to get all of the information in 'Permission entries', but I'm not sure how I would go about this, or if there's anything in the os library I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `os` with `os.system` function. The function will write any output to `stdout`.

```
import os

path_to_folder = "."
os.system(f'''icacls "{path_to_folder}"''')
```

If you want to have a call that returns output of the command as a string use:

```
import subprocess

path_to_folder = "."
output = subprocess.check_output(["icacls", path_to_folder])
print(output)
```

Keep in mind, obviously `icacls` is a windows tool, on linux the command would look different (`ls -la` maybe).

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by a blocking call?

Comment: Sorry, that was not correct. I edited the answer. Do not worry about that. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more information on the differences between the two.